# Z-index of aboslutely positioned element not working?

Tags: html, css

I am working with a page that has several input sections. Each section has a title (on the left) and a chevron icon to open/close the section (on the right). All of the row of the title can be clicked to open/close the section.

Now I also need to put another button (the one with `filter-icon`) inside this row, right before the open/close icon. I tried to assign a higher z-index to it, to put it 'on top' of the open/close row and make clickable, but it doesn't work. The z-index doesn't seem to be applied, and when I click on the `filter-icon`, the whole section is opened/closed, so the `filter-icon` seems to be placed 'under' the elements that control this, not on top as intended.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="pointer">
  <h4 class="form-title" style="position:relative" ng-click="toggleSection('sectionName')">
    <i class="fas fa-list"></i>Section title
    <i class="fas fa-filter filter-icon filter-icon-special" ng-click="toggleFilter('filterName')"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down chevron-icon" ng-class="{'chevron-turn': sections['sectionName']}"></i>
  </h4>
</div>
```

```
.filter-icon {
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.filter-icon-special {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}

.chevron-icon {
    float: right;
}

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way? What goes wrong?

Comment: The z-index doesn't seem to be applied, and when I click on the filter-icon, the whole section is opened/closed, so the filter-icon seems to be placed 'under' it.

Comment: You haven't provided any code which demonstrates that

Comment: Clicks "bubble" to elements below the top element, so it doesn't tell you anything about where the icon is placed. You need to stop the bubbling when the icon is clicked to prevent other click handlers from triggering.

Comment: To do what  @GuyIncognito suggests, you have to call `stopPropagation()` on the event object to stop the bubbling.

Comment: You should not use floats in 2020